# where days between 28 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING -> what data range is taking

Tags: hive, where-clause

I am creating a code to check the last 28 days of a table.

I  came across with this code

```
 WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY abs_wd.abs_wd_employee_id ORDER BY abs_wd.date_diff RANGE BETWEEN 28 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

My question is: Is this taking from yesterdays day to 28s back from yesterday? In another way, if I use only "PRECEDING", is this already counting from Yesterday or I have to add the "1" for that"

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

In hive window clause, the word `PRECEDING` means the number of rows previous to the current row. Similarly the word `FOLLOWING` would me the rows following after the current row.

For e.g. in your query `BETWEEN 28 PRECEDING` would basically mean 28 rows behind the **current row**.

So answer your question, by **default** the window works on the **current row** but if you want to start it from the previous window you would need to have a range which would start from 1 row preceding *(as you have correctly done in the question)*, like below:

```
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY abs_wd.abs_wd_employee_id ORDER BY abs_wd.date_diff ROWS BETWEEN 28 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
```

**Example:**

Based on the sample cloudera customers dataset, I ran a sum aggregate on the orders table with a window of 2 PRECEDING and 1 PRECEDING. If you look into the row 4, the window function returns a sum of total orders in a window from yesterday's date and day before yesterday's date.

[image]

Query used in the example:

```
sum(total_orders) over(order by order_date rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding) as window_result
```

More on window function in [hive doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics#LanguageManualWindowingAndAnalytics-WINDOWclause).

Comment: Ohhhh, so if I wanna count from yesterday to 28 days before from yesterday, should I use 'BETWEEN 28 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING' or 'BETWEEN 28 PRECEDING AND PRECEDING' ?  Thanks!

Comment: @Robbie Updated my answer. It needs to be `Between 28 Preceding and 1 Preceding`. I have also added a sample example for better understanding,